# 2+ share on facebook button with differen titles

Tags: facebook, button, share

i am looking for answer for 1 week.

I want to create **many "share on facebook" buttons on 1 page**. But they must have **different** og:image, og:title etc. How can I do this?

---

I found a way, but I don't like it, I have a page.php, every button will share page.php?id=n different id, in 'head' I set og:title depends of page's ID.

So the same page will be share with different links (I don't know if it's good for google)

Hope you understand me :) thanks )

Answer (score 0):

There is no other way.

Each Sharebutton must point to a different URL if they should display a different counter, so you can either create a new page for every sharebutton (page1.php, page2.php) or use the ID-approach (page.php?id=1), which makes a lot more sense. You can use `mod_rewrite` so you can use page/1, page/2 etc..

If you're searching for a solution where you can use the og-tags as parameters for the like-button: You cannot do that